# What kind of services should I use for accessing sensors data in background?

Tags: android, wear-os

I successfully used a service to do a certain task in the foreground. Now, to do it in the background, I'd remove the `handler.removeCallbacks` method in `onDestroy()`.

But this would also prevents me from stopping the service using `stopService(intent)`.

I saw on the official docs that I should *maybe* use JobScheduler (as I target API 28).

Here is a more precise indication of my code :

```
public class MainActivity {
    private Intent intent;    
    onCreate() {
        if (intent == null) {
            intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        }
    }
    startService(intent);
    ... // Then is some code to  stop the service if needed with  stopService(intent)
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
public class myService {
    private Handler handler = null;
    private static Runnable runnable = null;
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running service times " + i);
            i++;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I would like it to run in the background (even if the device is locked) but still being able to disable the service (or JobScheduler?).

What are your suggestions?

Comment: The question in the title of your post appears to be a different one than the one you've asked in the body of your post.  What is your actual question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey sorry I'm not great at explaining, so in English it's even worse... I think the body explains better I'll try rephrasing the title.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

or [job dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)

and there is a lot of options like
SyncAdapter, Bound services, Intent Service

you can use one of these options according to your need